Drawing a pattern(with dots) using turtle in python
I am trying to make a hirst painting (dot pattern) using the turtle in python. I managed to achieve it. Hirst_painting_dot_pattern.But my for loop isn't working the way I have expected. It's omitting the last iteration.
In the code below, my for loop isn't making the last dot. So, I have added one more line at the end of the loop to make the last dot. But I don't understand why the last dot is not drawn, though its within the range. Can somebody explain me?
import turtle as t
import random
tim = t.Turtle()
screen = t.Screen()
color_list = [(202, 164, 110), (240, 245, 241), (236, 239, 243), (149, 75, 50), (222, 201, 136), (53,    93, 123), (170, 154, 41), (138, 31, 20), (134, 163, 184), (197, 92, 73), (47, 121, 86), (73, 43, 35), (145, 178, 149), (14, 98, 70), (232, 176, 165), (160, 142, 158), (54, 45, 50), (101, 75, 77), (183, 205, 171), (36, 60, 74), (19, 86, 89), (82, 148, 129), (147, 17, 19), (27, 68, 102), (12, 70, 64), (107, 127, 153), (176, 192, 208), (168, 99, 102)]
t.colormode(255)
tim.speed("fastest")
tim.penup()
tim.setpos(-200, -200)
tim.pendown()
x = -200
y = -200
for yax in range(10):
    for xax in range(10):
        tim.pendown()
        tim.dot(20, random.choice(color_list))
        tim.penup()
        tim.setpos(x, y)
        x += 50
    y += 50
    x = -200
tim.dot(20, random.choice(color_list))
tim.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()


I'm pretty sure it is getting drawn - I get a 10x10 grid of dots when I run your program. The last dot might just be faint?

The first dot is drawn at -200, -200, and you then call tim.setpos(x, y) for coordinates -200, -200, so the next dot will overwrite the first. Continuing the loops, they will both finish at a point before the last dot is drawn. So always set the pen position before drawing the dot inside the loops, so it will always use the correct coordinates. This also eliminates the need for the final call to tim.dot after both loops terminate. I have also modified your code to automatically increment the x and y values, thus:
for y in range(-200, 251, 50):
    for x in range(-200, 251, 50):
        tim.setpos(x, y)
        tim.pendown()
        tim.dot(20, random.choice(color_list))
        tim.penup()
tim.hideturtle(), 


This answer correctly explains why you're seeing the unexpected behavior, as well as providing a suggestion to take advantage of your range() variables and parameters. I'd generalize it a step further by using constants:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import random


color_list = [...]  # fill in with your colors
screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
t = Turtle()
t.speed("fastest")
size = 225
gap = 50
dot_size = 20

for y in range(-size, size + 1, gap):
    for x in range(-size, size + 1, gap):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x, y)
        t.pendown()
        t.dot(dot_size, random.choice(color_list))

t.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()

This version also properly centers the pattern on the screen.
If you prefer to use a dot count rather than a size, you can compute the size dynamically:
dots_per_row = 10
dot_size = 20
gap = 50
size = dots_per_row * gap // 2

